# One date won't convert from string

Tags: nsdateformatter

I am converting dates in the format o "mm/dd/yyyy" to NSDates. For some inexplicable reason, 11/3/1968 converts to nil. 11/2/1968, 11/4/1968 are fine, but not 11/3/1968!?!?!? I have used the sandbox to try several different dates, but ONLY 11/3/1968 converts to nil.

I have over 5,000 dates get successfully converted from 1926 to through 1971. Only this one date will not convert.

This is from my playground just to make the point:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let date1 = "11/2/1968"
let myDate1 = dateFormatter.date(from: date1)   //returns November 2, 1968
let date2 = "11/3/1968"
let myDate2 = dateFormatter.date(from: date2)   //returns nil
let date3 = "11/4/1968"
let myDate3 = dateFormatter.date(from: date3)   //returns November 4, 1968
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You forgot to show your code that is converting it.

Answer (score 0):

What's your locale?

In your locale Nov, 3 1968 might be a day where daylight saving time changed and 0:00 until 0:59 was skipped.

If this is the case set the locale to a country where this behavior doesn't occur.

Comment: I'm in eastern time. Interesting thought. I will experiment with your answer.

Comment: I just ran the code again (after we skipped to daylight saving time), and it worked. However, November 3, 1968 would not have been a day we went to daylight saving, but it might have been a day we went back to standard time. So, that would mean that that it would have done the same hour twice! Also, technically, the time changes are supposed to occur at 2:00 so that there will never be a day change. Thanks for your clever answer. I will investigate more.